# Bind userControl into DataTemplate in wpf

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have dynamically create usercontrol, this usercontrol i want bind into DataTemplate.

EX:

```
 usercontrol:
   GridWidget propWidget = new GridWidget(GridWidgetDefinition);

 DataTemplate:
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupBoxTemplate">
       <GroupBox  Header="{Binding Name}">
          <control:GridWidget/>
       </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How to bind propWidget usercontrol into inside Groupbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific problem you can bind Content property of your group box with the control. Something like this,

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupBoxTemplate">
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}" Content="{Binding Control}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Not sure if this the best way to solve it.